# How to fix: variable in return section of render method not updating when render is called a second time React

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, pagination, render

I am pulling in data from a Flask api to React asynchronously and updating the page after the data has been received. The new data correctly updates the state, and re-rendering the page shows the new data, except that when the number of data items increases, the number of pages from my Pagination class does not also increase.

I have printed out the new state and the new number of data items in the render method so I can see that the state has updated and render is being called.

Here is the render method:

```
render() {
    console.log("Render being called!");
    console.log(this.state)
    const { job_data, currentJobs, currentPage, totalPages } = this.state;
    const totalJobs = job_data.length;
    console.log(totalJobs);  // Total jobs prints out correctly here as 800

    if (totalJobs === 0) return null;

    const headerClass = ['text-dark py-2 pr-4 m-0', currentPage ? 'border-gray border-right' : ''].join(' ').trim();

    return (
      <div className="content">
        <Grid fluid>
          <Row>
           <div className="d-flex flex-row py-4 align-items-right"> 
            // totalJobs should be updated here but isn't 
            <Pagination totalRecords={totalJobs} pageLimit={6} pageNeighbours={1} onPageChanged={this.onPageChanged} />
            </div>
```

Here is my async componentsDidMount call that updates my state:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Async component componentDidMount")
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/');
    console.log("Waiting for new jobs...")
    const json = await response.json();

    this.setState({ job_data: json.eqtls }); 

    console.log(this.state.job_data)
    console.log("Got new jobs!")
    const currentJobs = this.state.job_data.slice(0, 0 + 6);
    const totalPages = 10;
    const currentPage = 1;
    this.setState({ currentPage, currentJobs, totalPages });
  }
```

Since the state is updated and render is called again and prints out that totalJobs has increased, the number of pages should increase, but it isn't.

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous. There's zero guarantee that immediately plucking `job_data` off state after your first `setState` will contain the updated contents. See the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: In componentDidMount you only need to do one setState at the end: `this.setState({ job_data: json.eqtls,currentPage:1,curentJobs:json.eqtls.slice(0,5) });` Also setState is async so after you do the first setState this.state is not what you think it is.

Comment: With the few tests that I did I found that the first call of setState called the render method before updating the state so the second call is just to trigger re-rendering with the new data. With out async the fetch method was not waiting for the new data before calling set state, which is why I chose it. I am printing out the fresh data in the render method and it still isn't updating. So my question is: given that the state (and totalJobs) has updated by the time the render method is called, why doesn't render's return method with Pagination see that?

Answer (score 0):

I can see few problems ems:
- async componentDidMount()?
Use inner functions :

    `componentDidMount() {
      async invokeApi() {
        //api call here 
      }
      invokeApi();
    }`

- in this use case, I don't see need to setState twice. Extract variables and use it once for readability.

Please note that `setState` is asynchronous and doesn't guarantee the order. Update componentDidUpdate to effectively handle unwanted rerender.

Comment: It still has the same problem. The data and the pages with this method do not update unless I switch between pages and then the data only updates.

Comment: @kuck1 I don't see anywhere in your code where you would update the pages after initially setting it in componentDidMount but maybe I'll try it one more time; setState is asynchronous so you're not even setting any data in componentDidMount, nor does it make any sense to call setStiate twice.

Comment: I see, so what method should I use to update pages after initially setting it up?